# Format time algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am really struggling to solve human readable duration format algorithm. I have solved the most of it, but there are some mistakes anyway which I cannot solve for a while. Some tests pass, while others don't. Please help me it solve it.

**The code**

```
function formatDuration (seconds) {
  // Complete this function
  var minutes = Math.round(seconds / 60);
  var thisSeconds = Math.round(seconds % 60);
  var hours = Math.round(seconds / 3600);
  var days = Math.round(seconds / 86400);
  var years = Math.round(seconds / 31536000);

  var stringYear = "year";
  var stringDay = "day";
  var stringHour = "hour";
  var stringMinute = "minute";
  var stringSecond = "second";

  if (years > 1) {
    stringYear = "years";  
  } else if (days > 1) {
    stringDay = "days";
  } else if (hours > 1) {
    stringHour = "hours";
  } else if (thisSeconds > 1) {
    stringSecond = "seconds";  
  } else if (minutes > 1) {
    stringMinute = "minutes"; 
  }

  if (minutes >= 60) {
    hours = Math.round(minutes/60);
    minutes = Math.abs(minutes - hours*60);

    if (minutes > 1) {
      stringMinute = "minutes"; 
    }
  } 

  if (hours >= 24) {
    days = Math.round(hours/24);
    if (days > 1) {
      stringDay = "days";  
    }
    hours = hours - days*24;
    stringHour = "hours";
  }

  if (days > 365) {
    days = Math.abs(days - years*365);
    stringDay = "days";
  }

  var obj = new Map();
  obj.set(stringYear, years);
  obj.set(stringDay, days);
  obj.set(stringHour, hours);
  obj.set(stringMinute, minutes);
  obj.set(stringSecond, thisSeconds);

  var empArr = [];

  obj.forEach(function (value, key, mapObj) {

    if (value == 0) {
      obj.delete(key);   
    }

    var res = value + " " + key;

    if (value > 0) {

      empArr.push(res);

      formatStrings(empArr);

    }

  }); 

  return formatStrings(empArr);

}

function formatStrings(arr) {
    return arr.length == 1 ? arr[0] : arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1).join(", ") + " and " + arr[arr.length - 1];
    //console.log(str);
}


formatDuration(3600);
```

**Test results**

[image]

Comment: What are the inputs you're getting that are failing? What are the inputs that are working?

Comment: I do not know they do not provide that.

Comment: You should use Math.floor instead of Math.round, because otherwise "118" will become 2 mins 58 seconds instead of 1 min 58 seconds

Comment: Thank you, James you are so helpful. It works now. However, I do not know why second does not change to seconds when there are more than one seconds.

Comment: You have a big if/else if block.  That's not going to work if years > 1 *and* seconds > 1 (it will just perform the first matching condition's code)  You need a bunch of independent ifs.

Comment: But how they are related to each other, they are different variables?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.round performs rounding (rounding up if the value would be above .5).
use Math.floor everywhere to take the truncated part.

I would also use modulo to avoid all the complicated logic you've added.
So

```
var minutes = Math.round(seconds / 60);
```

would become

```
var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60) % 60;
```

and so on.